# Get contour of set of rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

I am looking for an algorithm to get contour of a figure created by a set of non-overlapping rectangles. The figure can be of any shape but it is simply-connected, i.e. contains no holes.

I need an idea on how to write a function like that:

```
IEnumerable<Point> GetContour( IEnumerable<Rect> rects )
```

Time complexity of the algorithm is not important, it just has to perform in reasonable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do this in two passes. The first would convert the rectangles into a collection of points (in winding order), including the points where the corner of another rectangle is a point along an edge. That way you'll end up with a graph of points where you can easily detect which points are shared between which rectangles.

With that, just search your graph for the first point with no shared rects and start walking routes along points that have up to no shared rects, or two shared rects where the previous point has no shared rects, until you get back to the starting point.

You'll need to maintain a stack for your route, as well as a map of previously explored points.

I did exactly this just recently (although it wasn't limited to rects and I already had the first pass done) and it worked quite nicely. I was seeing it able to calculate a route in a graph of about 30 points more times in a second than I could count in an int, so performance seemed pretty good, although that was in C++.

Comment: Thank you, nice idea and rather easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a specific case of the *concave hull* problem.. many algorithms do exist to solve the opposite *convex hull* problems:

- Jarvis March ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm)) O(n^2)
- Graham Scan ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan)) O(nlogn)

These are simplest ones, there are at least 3 more but they just optimize performance, that is not one of your primary goals.

I think that **Jarvis March** can be easily adapted to your case, in which you just have rectangles. Think about the fact that on every passage this algorithm usually takes the first point on the right of the line that crosses last 2 points of the hull you are calculating, so with a better choose rule you can adapt it to be concave in the specific case of rectangles.

In any case there is also a specific **concave hull** algorithm described here: [link](http://ubicomp.algoritmi.uminho.pt/local/), you can also download their API [here](http://www.concavehull.com/) (this should be the paper that describes the algorithm: [link](http://en.scientificcommons.org/22155331))

Comment: Is Concave hull unique? I am not sure if we can apply this. Care to elaborate a little more?

Comment: I think much the complexity of these algorithms is deducing information we already know - winding and inside/ outside. We know it for each rectangle, and we can use that information to help us find the composite contour.

Comment: Yes, you know inside/out for the rectangles but you have to consider them just as points when you want to trace the contour, since in any case you'll need to see which points of the rectangles are on the hull you are calculating and you can't know it a priori. Concave Hull is not unique, but in this case it can be if rectangles are aligned (this is not specified in the question).

I'll try to develop a full solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jack: The OP specified the Rect class. If it is the same one as in .NET, it is aligned.

Comment: @Jack. If you're working with enclosed shapes and know all the contact points you can use our knowledge of inside/outside when tracing the contours. Treating them just as independant points loses that information unnecessarily.

Comment: If rectangles are not overlapping but they are ALWAYS in contact that's true, you can just ignore points that stay over an edge of rectangle.. but it's not clear, he says no holes but it's no clear if he doesn't want holes at the end or if there aren't holes at all..